# How to call 3 different stored procedure in one database connection?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a c# console app client and I am trying to connect to mysql database.

I have a main method called select.

This method return n of rows.

I am looping through results, and for each one I am calling another method call `GetProductAttributes` and after I get the results I am calling another method called `UpdateProductAttributesJsonField`

Here is my code :

```
public void Select(int shopId)
{
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetProducts", new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString)))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@last_modified_date", ""));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@ShopId", shopId));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var id = int.Parse(dataReader["Id"].ToString());
            var attributes = GetProductAttributes(id);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attributes.ToArray());
            UpdateProductAttributesJsonField(id, json);
        }
        //dataReader.Close();
    }
}

public Dictionary<string, string> GetProductAttributes(int Id)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetProductAttributes", new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString)))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Id", Id));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        //CommandBehavior.CloseConnection

        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            result.Add(dataReader["name"].ToString(), dataReader["value"].ToString());
        }
        //dataReader.Close();
    }
    return result;
}


public void UpdateProductAttributesJsonField(int productId, string json)
{
    using( MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UpdateArticleAttributes", new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString)))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@articleId", productId));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@json", json));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); // cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

}
```

Here is my initialize method

```
private void Initialize()
{
    server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShopwareDBServer"];
    database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"];
    uid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseUser"];
    password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePassword"];
    port = "3306";
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "Port=" + port + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";" + "Convert Zero Datetime=True";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

I am getting this error :

> {"error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior
>   to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred
>   because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was
>   reached."}

Comment: but this is not a proper solution. I can increase the max pool size, but I want to do with  one connection open.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to reach your goal without additional connections. Last time I have checked the MySql provider doesn't support the MultipleActiveRecordSet option so each connection that serves a DataReader cannot be used for other tasks until the reader is closed.

Comment: Each Connection implements `IDisposable`.  If you never call `Close()` or `Dispose()`, then the connection never goes back to the pool.  Why are you creating all these connection objects?  Either re-use or create as needed.  You may want to use one of these instead of the connection in `Initialize()` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, `DataReader` is `IDisposable`.  Make sure that just about every database object is encapsulated by the `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Data Reader in your code, you need to close the connection before opening a new one.

It may seem to be a suggestion rather than answering the question, but let me show you another way to do the same thing.

You want to call 3 procedures then why you are not combining these three procedures and create a new one in the database and call that procedure. I think, this way you need only one connection and your problem will be solved.

By the way, this is not possible to call three procedures on the same connection that uses "Data Reader".

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use maximum connection pool size may be in your code you no where write `connection.close()` so connection size is increase with time so just make sure you close connections in finally block.

First restart MySQL so it will close all the connection and change your code accordingly. And this issue is not due to calling 3 stored procedures in one connection and if you want to do it is done in multiple way.

- Either you call one stored procedure and call other procedures from the first one.
- You also call stored procedures step by step from c# code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the connection state is opened or closed; this can help you decrease your maximum connection pool size.

You can write the code like this:

```
If(Connection.State == Closed) {
    Connection.open
}
```